# Count the number of elements, and then assign class

Tags: jquery

Is there a way that I can count how many elements are within another element and then output a class to the child elements based on that number?

For example;

```
<ul class="paging">

    <li><a href="#">content</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">content</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">content</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">content</a></li>

</ul>
```

As there are 4 list elements each list element would be assigned a class of `list-4` or something similar. If there are 5 `list-5` etc. etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

```
   $('.paging').each(function() {
      var listElements = $(this).children('li');
      var listCount = listElements.length //get number of list elements
      listElements.each(function() {
           $(this).addClass('list-' + listCount);
       });
    });
```

Comment: It was correct for the question asked, however, this now works for multiple lists with the same class.

Answer (score 1):

You can count the length of a jQuery object by using `.length`. For your example, the following will work:

```
$('.paging').each(function() { 
    var children = $(this).children('li');
    children.addClass('list-'+children.length);
});
```

Since we use the `children()`, this will only include direct children (i.e. anything inside of the `<li>` elements will be ignored).

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gHqdq/)